# Creating unit test project for windows application

Tags: unit-testing

Hi I am creating a unit test project for a windows application.
In my windows application I am using some windows service.
In my application I have a datacache class which calls to the web service directly using the following code:

```
public List<GetCMSCaseSearchResultsResult> getCaseSearchResults(GetCMSCaseSearchResultsParameters oSearchParameters)
{
    bool bIsOffshoreUser = Config.sRoleList.Contains("AP3_OFFSHORE_USER");
    string sResult = oCMSWebServiceClient.GetCMSCaseSearchResults(oSearchParameters, bIsOffshoreUser);
    return Config.DeserializeObject(sResult, typeof(List<GetCMSCaseSearchResultsResult>)) as List<GetCMSCaseSearchResultsResult>;
}
```

Now I need to create the test method for the method `getCaseSearchResults()` in my test project. But when I call this method it's giving me a NullReferenceException as shown in the image:

[image: Error from visual studio]

Please let us know your suggestion for that

Comment: Please edit your question and enter the error as text. As an image it can't be found by searchers.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured in CMSTestproject.dll but not handled in user code

Additional information: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object